# three.js update geometry of json file

Tags: json, three.js

i am working on a project and i got stuck on this one thing, i got a bvh file with an animation which i put on a biped in 3dsmax then i export every frame in to a json file with the thee.js json exporter and then when it gets played i remove the old mesh and add a new one. This causes the model to upload multiple times, which ofcourse is not what i want.

I use the jsonloader and i wondered if there was a way to update only the geometry every frame? Also i made those seperate files because i dont use a skin and i dont have morphtargets because i use a bvh file in 3dsmax.

It would be awesome if someone could help me with this

Example: http://www.deschaatssport.nl/3dsportsvisualiser/versie3/?p=3# (press the play button)

Mathijs Jansen

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your JSON exporter keeps the number and order of faces/vertices intact, you could do something like this:

- Load the initial model as you do now
- Set `geometry.dynamic = true;`
- Load the rest of the JSON files with plain old AJAX (alternatively you could combine the frame JSON files to one file, whatever so you have access to all of them through your own code)
- For each frame, loop the new frame vertex position array (found in the JSON for each frame) and overwrite the coordinates of your existing geometry vertices (`geometry.vertices[i].x = myframevertices[i][0]; etc...`)
- Set geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true; and render the frame.

Again I'm just assuming that each JSON file has the same amount and order of faces/vertices, and only the vertex positions change in each frame. I'm not completely sure if it works like that.

There has also been some (experimental?) work on BVH support with Three.js. You might have success searching around, I don't know if there is anything usable though. One related effort here: https://github.com/akjava/BVH-Motion-Creator